# run html5 application as windows executable

Tags: windows, winforms, html, webkit

I have looked all over the web for this sort of thing i've found lots of similar questions and articles but none answer this. I have a large HTML 5 application and i want to run it as an executable on windows as a full screen native application. I can image you could do it through a webkit later in c++ but i don't know c++ and don't have time to learn it thoroughly unfortunetly.

Can anyone suggest the best way to make my html5 application run as a full screen windows app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution, I downloaded Chromium portable and put the app files in the same folder, then I start chromium portable with a .bat file like so:

```
@echo off
start %cd%/appdata/ChromiumPortable.exe --kiosk %cd%/appdata/app.html
```

which tells it to start in full screen mode and go straight to the app.html home page, hope it helps other people

Answer (score 6):

Rename the file extension to `.hta`

This will make it a [HTML Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application)

Put this inside your head.

```
<hta:application
   showintaskbar = "no"
   caption = "no"
   border = "thick"
   contextmenu = "no"
   icon = "path_to_icon.ico"
   innerborder = "no"
   scroll = "no"
   singleinstance = "yes" 
   resizable = "no"
   windowState = "maximize"
>
```

Comment: that's billiant never heard of that before, but unfortunetly it runs ies rendering engine where as my app has html5 features and jquery etc and only reall yworks well in chrome do you know of a similar software i could use?

Comment: You may want to try something like [Chrome Frame](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/) although I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 2):

This looks promising: http://www.tidesdk.org/

You can develop apps with HTML5 and JavaScript and deploy them on windows, linux and even mac.

Comment: TideSDK is defunct now.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Windows 8 App using HTML5 CSS & JavaScript:
http://dev.windows.com

Comment: This does not seem a approach to take at this time for anything that could be used with the general public for the next few years, as Windows 8 isn't fully released yet. You might want to include a small example though?