# how to use javascript or jquery in windows form?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, windows

I'm making this application in c#.net, just for personal use and I'm just making it for practice and to learn more about c#.net programming.

I know java script is meant for web applications, but maybe there are ways to use them in windows applications as well.

Comment: If you want to learn JavaScript, your best bet is to focus on writing an application that uses JavaScript - an HTML5 app, or maybe learning Node. There's pretty much zero overlap between a .Net app and a JavaScript one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553155/run-html5-application-as-windows-executable

Comment: @AdrianWragg: `"if you want to learn JavaScript"`? where did you get that from?? it wasn't the sentence that says `"to learn more about c#.net programming"` was it?

Comment: @musefan No, it was from his second paragraph where he asked about using JavaScript. That implied to me that he may have also wanted to learn about JavaScript and its usage.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use them directly.

You could technically make a library that parses JQuery and does the same things... or you could make a C# equivalent of the same functionality, but that seems like more work than it's worth.

If you are looking to practice c#.net then practice c#.net, even if you could use javascript/JQuery that wouldn't get you much c# practice would it.

Answer (score 0):

Regular windows (desktop) applications will not run on javascript.
However, windows 8 **store** applications (either for windows 8 desktop, or windows mobile) can be created using HTML5 & js.

This series should give you a decent start: http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-windows-store-apps-with-html5-jump-start#?fbid=ldvGrgy_tPQ